# Error when deploying a project on symfony 2.8

Tags: php, redis, symfony-2.8

I have linux mint, when I try to start a project I get the error: 
**This page isn’t working.**

Having executed the command: `php app / check.php` writes that everything is OK and the system is ready to run (**Your system is ready to run Symfony projects**)

When executing the cache clear command (or any other command via the console):

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

or

```
php app/console cache:clear -e prod
```

I get an error:

> [RuntimeException]                                              The
>   factory can only instantiate \Redis classes: Redis asked

**langu2.loc.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.tld
ServerAlias langu2.loc

DocumentRoot /var/www/langu2.loc/web
<Directory /var/www/langu2.loc/web>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

# uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
# or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
# <Directory /var/www/langu2.loc>
#     Options FollowSymlinks
# </Directory>

# optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
# which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
# not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
<Directory /var/www/langu2.loc/web/bundles>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine Off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/langu2_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/langu2_access.log combined
```

**parameters.yml:**

```
    parameters:
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: 3306
database_name: langu
database_user: root
database_password: 123456
admin_database_host: 127.0.0.1
admin_database_port: 3306
admin_database_name: langu
admin_database_user: root
admin_database_password: 123456
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
mailer_override_address: {  }
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
google_client_id: null
google_client_secret: null
google_app_name: null
google_app_scopes: null
tokbox_api_key: null
tokbox_api_secret: null
tokbox_session_routed_mode: false
mangopay_client_id: null
mangopay_client_password: null
mangopay_base_url: null
mangopay_debug_mode: true
fixer_key: d7a2c4d1ad4672aafe12a35ef07426e3
langu_exchange_rate_fee: !!float 0
langu_wallets:
    EUR:
        wallet: 17988934
        user: 17988933
    GBP:
        wallet: 17988936
        user: 17988933
    USD:
        wallet: 17988935
        user: 17988933
    PLN:
        wallet: 17988937
        user: 17988933
refund_fee: 0.15
refund_compensation: 0.15
refund_deductions_limit: 0.5
snippets:
    google_analytics: false
    zopim: false
    go_squared: false
    hotjar: false
    facebook: false
    google_tag_manager: false
    google_remarketing: false
    autopilot: false
router.request_context.host: langu2.loc
router.request_context.scheme: http
redis.password: null
redis.port: 6379
liip_imagine_data_path:
    - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/'
    - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/'
    - '%kernel.root_dir%/../uploads/'
main_domain: langu2.loc
allowed_mimetypes_lib:
    - text/plain
    - text/richtext
    - application/rtf
    - image/jpg
    - image/jpeg
    - image/png
    - image/gif
    - application/pdf
    - video/avi
    - video/msvideo
    - video/mpeg
    - video/H264
    - video/ogg
    - video/mp4
    - audio/mp4
    - audio/mpeg
    - audio/ogg
    - application/vnd.ms-excel
    - application/msword
    - application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
    - application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet
    - application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation
    - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
    - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    - application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
    - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
max_size_lib: 10485760
```

**redis.yml:**

```
snc_redis:
clients:
    default:
        type: phpredis
        alias: default
        dsn: redis://localhost
        logging: false
session:
    client: default
    prefix: "session:php:"
```

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "patryk/langu_2",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php",
        "api/ApiKernel.php",
        "api/ApiCache.php",
        "admin/AdminKernel.php",
        "admin/AdminCache.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.1",
    "troopers/mangopay-bundle": "^2.0",
    "pinano/select2-bundle": "^4.0",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "oneup/uploader-bundle": "^1.7",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.6",
    "ocramius/proxy-manager": "^1.0",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^1.32",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.4",
    "webit/bcmath-bundle": "^1.2",
    "opentok/opentok": "^2.4",
    "debesha/doctrine-hydration-profiler-bundle": "^1.2",
    "willdurand/js-translation-bundle": "^2.6",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.4",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.3",
    "cocur/slugify": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "^1.0",
    "hampe/zurb-ink-bundle": "^2.2",
    "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "^1.0",
    "snc/redis-bundle": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.2",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.3",
    "knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle": "^1.5",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.12",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^3.2",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "^2.1",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^1.3",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^3.2",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "~6",
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "~1.0",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.1",
    "league/iso3166": "^2.1",
    "autologic-web/redirect-bundle": "^0.2.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "component-dir": "web/assets"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": null
}
}
```